# How to access app usage statistics in a Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make a Flutter app that displays a pie graph of time spent on each app. How can I get information about the time spent on each app?

I have no idea how to solve this issue, and I'll really appreciate any advice!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a plugin which hooks into Android's App Usage API: see it on pub [here](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage).

I haven't used it myself, but it looks to make gathering app usage relatively simple:

```dart
List<AppUsageInfo> infoList = await AppUsage().getAppUsage(startDate, endDate);
```

If this doesn't do what you need, or you need iOS support as well, I don't think there are any other plugins doing what you need, so you would probably have to write them to hook into the `DeviceActivity` API on iOS or `UsageStateManager` on Android.